# Can a server respond to a ping when that machine has gone down?

Tags: ssh, ping

I have inherited administration of a computing cluster that my research group uses at my uni. I got an email from one of the users that the web interface isn't responding. I can ping the machine, but I cant ssh in

If I ping the address I can find the host and I get a response:

```
ping -c 20 cluster.host.myschool.edu
 ...
 ...
```

20 packets transmitted, 19 packets recieved 5.0% packet loss

But if I try to ssh:

```
ssh -v me@cluster.host.myschool.edu
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to cluster.myschool.vt.edu [xxx.xx.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
```

and then it just hangs forever I have to kill it it wont give me any error message after waiting several minutes.

What could possibly be causing this issue?  I am certain at this point I will have to go out to the physical machine to figure this out, but It makes me wonder: Can I get a response from the address but the computer has crashed?

I don't think the ssh server could have just gone down because the web-sever that hosts a graphical interface is giving a similar issue if I try to go to the site where I would log-in in a browser I don't get a server not found, or connection timed out error firefox just keeps loading the page indefinitely.

I am not asking for help debugging this (although I would take suggestions) I am wondering how these various connections work and why is it that the machine is answering the ping's but does not seem to respond to anything else

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "down."  If a machine has no power or network, it cannot respond to a ping.  A Ryan stated in his answer, your machine is *up*.  However, it is just not working properly.

Comment: In short, that is exactly the answer I was looking for I didn't realize that the machine could respond to a ping when it can't properly establish a connection. I guess the ping is like bouncing something off it? ie its working because its there, but that doesn't mean I can get in?

Comment: The machine is up.  The network is up.  That we can tell by the fact it responded to pings.  Beyond that, something is not right.  Where that issue is...  thats a different story.

Comment: @Ajay Machine can respond to pings, despite having some service issues (e.g. SSH is down or under DDoS). When machine can't respond to pings, can still respond to [arping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping) despite firewall being on.

Answer (score 2):

It does appear that the server is responding to SSH, it's not completing your login. That's why ping works. Ping often works even when a server is completely unresponsive in every other way.

Try to see if you can get more info like this

```
ssh -vvv me@cluster.host.myschool.edu
```

There could be a variety of things going wrong on the server. e.g failed disk, out of disk space, memory issues, DNS issues... who knows. In cases like this, daemons may respond but not function as expected.

Comment: I am not able to get any more info that way, but it looks like this is a more widespread issue. I am in the chemistry department and we have a few all under the names `chem.myschool.edu` some of them with websites hosted some without, but all of them are unresponsive in the browser, and via ssh (or well not completing the login, since they are responding) Thanks for your help!